# How can I send a mail from unix mutt client with both html and body in html?

Tags: shell, unix, email-client, mutt

I need to send a mail from unix thru mutt client. 
I tried sending a mail with html body :

mutt -e "my_hdr Content-Type: text/html" $userEmail -s "Workflow - Query Execution on Stage: $STGUPPER" < $htmlResultFile

WORKS.

Tried to send a mail with html attachment:

mutt -e "my_hdr Content-Type: text/html" -a $htmlResultFile  -s "attachment" $userEmail

WORKS!

But when I try to send a mail with both html body and html attachemnt, I'm not able to do that..

mutt -e "set Content-Type: text/html" $userEmail -a $htmlResultFile  -s "attachment" < 
$htmlResultFile

I get the html as attchment, but the body as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you'll have to craft the body yourself. Note that the content_type of a mixed body is `multipart/alternative`

I found this question interesting. Here's my take on it:

```
#!/bin/sh
# using mutt, send a mixed multipart text and html message:

usage() {
    echo "error: $1"
    echo "usage: $(basename $0) -t textfile -h htmlfile -s subject -r recipient"
    exit 1
}

textfile=""
htmlfile=""
subject=""
recipient=""

while getopts "t:h:s:r:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        t) textfile="$OPTARG" ;;
        h) htmlfile="$OPTARG" ;;
        s) subject="$OPTARG" ;;
        r) recipient="$OPTARG" ;;
        ?) usage "invalid option: -$OPTARG" ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

[ -z "$textfile" ] && usage "no textfile specified"
[ -z "$htmlfile" ] && usage "no htmlfile specified"
[ -z "$recipient" ] && usage "no recipient specified"
[ ! -f "$textfile" ] && usage "no such file: $textfile"
[ ! -f "$htmlfile" ] && usage "no such file: $htmlfile"

boundary=$(openssl rand -hex 24)
content_type="Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=$boundary"

##
body=$(cat - << END

--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

$(cat "$textfile")

--$boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

$(cat "$htmlfile")

--$boundary
END
)
##

echo "$body" | mutt -e "myhdr $content_type" -s "$subject" "$recipient"
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't manage to send **combined** plain text & HTML in mutt. So I ended up crafting the email by hand and piping to `sendmail -t`.

Example: https://github.com/kaihendry/sg-hackandtell/blob/master/list/maillist

This should give better results than justing sending HTML email.